# Can't edit or select anything in document after opening it in Microsoft Word unless I reopen it

Tags: microsoft-word

I've got a client I'm working with that is having an error I've never seen before and I can't seem to find anything about it. Here's the issues:

Client opens an Office Word file from their server and it opens. However, when they attempt to select anything in said file or edit it in any way, they can't. I tried and verified that the file isn't frozen. You can open up multiple files from the server and all documents have the same problem. So far as I know this is the only computer that is currently having the issue. Other people in the same office haven't complained about this problem.

I tried closing the file and having her re-open it, and the problem went away. This is an intermittent problem for her. Has anyone seen this?

Comment: define "can't". Your title states "error", what is it specifically.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I don't have an error code or anything like that to go off of. More specifically, I can open the Word document in question and it displays normally, but I can't do anything at all to the file. In fact, I have to close it via task manager, but according to task manager Word isn't frozen. I verified this because you can see the mouse icon blinking in the Word file, but you can't do anything to said file.

Comment: Sorry I know that's a bit confusing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Edit you question to include this information. Is this the only PC that has issues editing word files on the server?

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: I didn't for Word yet. She seems to be having this problem with Word and perhaps Excel, but not in Outlook. I had removed a problematic update for Outlook that was causing to open in safe mode, but she doesn't have any other issues with that application.

Comment: consider reinstalling word as an option.

Comment: Yeah I'll give that a shot and see what happens. Thank you for the suggestion. I take it no one has seen this sort of behavior in Word?

Comment: @JoshMcMullin Perhaps I might've seen something like it  when it wasn't activated or something but i'm not sure and I don't recall about reopening it, or even if that was a symptom of that. BTW, the word "pc" is old fashioned. And avoid the word "they" if it's ambiguous, it's clearer to say what is meant by "they" So i've edited your question appropriately. Your question would've got a -1 because of the undescriptive title. Imagine if a user said to you "weird ms word problem" that doesn't say much, does it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error was specifically tied to corrupted Office files. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  It might enhance the usefulness to others if you can expand your answer a little.  What makes you think that?  What did you do to solve it?